# XsD root element

Tags: java, xml

Не могу понять, как создать xml из java классов сгенерированных из xsd, 
есть класс Properties (и много других) отмеченный как rootElement, но как и какие классы туда подставлять мне не понятно,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Properties_Type", propOrder = {
"property"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
     Properties.class
 })
 public class PropertiesType {

@XmlElement(name = "Property", required = true)
protected List<PropertiesType.Property> property;

/**
 * Gets the value of the property property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the property property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getProperty().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link PropertiesType.Property }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<PropertiesType.Property> getProperty() {
    if (property == null) {
        property = new ArrayList<PropertiesType.Property>();
    }
    return this.property;
}


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="Key" type="{}String"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Value" type="{}String"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "key",
    "value"
})
public static class Property {

    @XmlElement(name = "Key", required = true)
    protected String key;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    protected String value;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the key property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the key property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setKey(String value) {
        this.key = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

}

```
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Properties")
public class Properties
extends PropertiesType
{


}


Properties properties = new Properties();
List<PropertiesType.Property> list = properties.getProperty();
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Но из xsd у меня было сгенерировано много классов, 
вот ObjectFactory

```
//
// This file was xml by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802
```

// See http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb 
   // Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
    // Generated on: 2016.03.14 at 12:17:11 PM MSK 
//

```
package xml;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

/**
* This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * xml in the xml package.
*

An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
* 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

```
private final static QName _ServerStatusDesc_QNAME = new QName("", "ServerStatusDesc");
private final static QName _AgencyId_QNAME = new QName("", "AgencyId");
private final static QName _SPName_QNAME = new QName("", "SPName");
private final static QName _UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRs_QNAME = new QName("", "UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRs");
private final static QName _RqUID_QNAME = new QName("", "RqUID");
private final static QName _SystemId_QNAME = new QName("", "SystemId");
private final static QName _UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRq_QNAME = new QName("", "UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRq");
private final static QName _BranchId_QNAME = new QName("", "BranchId");
private final static QName _OperUID_QNAME = new QName("", "OperUID");
private final static QName _StatusCode_QNAME = new QName("", "StatusCode");
private final static QName _StatusDesc_QNAME = new QName("", "StatusDesc");
private final static QName _CurAmt_QNAME = new QName("", "CurAmt");
private final static QName _StatusType_QNAME = new QName("", "StatusType");
private final static QName _RbBrchId_QNAME = new QName("", "RbBrchId");
private final static QName _RegionId_QNAME = new QName("", "RegionId");
private final static QName _RbTbBrchId_QNAME = new QName("", "RbTbBrchId");
private final static QName _RqTm_QNAME = new QName("", "RqTm");

/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: xml
 * 
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PropertiesType }
 * 
 */
public PropertiesType createPropertiesType() {
    return new PropertiesType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PayType }
 * 
 */
public PayType createPayType() {
    return new PayType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType createOperationDataType() {
    return new OperationDataType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.Chat }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.Chat createOperationDataTypeChat() {
    return new OperationDataType.Chat();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.Chat.Events }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.Chat.Events createOperationDataTypeChatEvents() {
    return new OperationDataType.Chat.Events();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.Chat.Operators }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.Chat.Operators createOperationDataTypeChatOperators() {
    return new OperationDataType.Chat.Operators();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType }
 * 
 */
public UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType() {
    return new UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType }
 * 
 */
public UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType() {
    return new UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Properties }
 * 
 */
public Properties createProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PropertiesType.Property }
 * 
 */
public PropertiesType.Property createPropertiesTypeProperty() {
    return new PropertiesType.Property();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PrimaryOperationType }
 * 
 */
public PrimaryOperationType createPrimaryOperationType() {
    return new PrimaryOperationType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link BankInfoType }
 * 
 */
public BankInfoType createBankInfoType() {
    return new BankInfoType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ErrorInfoStatusType }
 * 
 */
public ErrorInfoStatusType createErrorInfoStatusType() {
    return new ErrorInfoStatusType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ErrorType }
 * 
 */
public ErrorType createErrorType() {
    return new ErrorType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OrgDataType }
 * 
 */
public OrgDataType createOrgDataType() {
    return new OrgDataType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link MasterSystemType }
 * 
 */
public MasterSystemType createMasterSystemType() {
    return new MasterSystemType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ErrorInfoType }
 * 
 */
public ErrorInfoType createErrorInfoType() {
    return new ErrorInfoType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationInfoType }
 * 
 */
public OperationInfoType createOperationInfoType() {
    return new OperationInfoType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ExtraTermType }
 * 
 */
public ExtraTermType createExtraTermType() {
    return new ExtraTermType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OrigCurAmtType }
 * 
 */
public OrigCurAmtType createOrigCurAmtType() {
    return new OrigCurAmtType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link StatusType }
 * 
 */
public StatusType createStatusType() {
    return new StatusType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link AcctBalType }
 * 
 */
public AcctBalType createAcctBalType() {
    return new AcctBalType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationStatusType }
 * 
 */
public OperationStatusType createOperationStatusType() {
    return new OperationStatusType();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PayType.BankInfo }
 * 
 */
public PayType.BankInfo createPayTypeBankInfo() {
    return new PayType.BankInfo();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.AcctBal }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.AcctBal createOperationDataTypeAcctBal() {
    return new OperationDataType.AcctBal();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.Chat.Events.Event }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.Chat.Events.Event createOperationDataTypeChatEventsEvent() {
    return new OperationDataType.Chat.Events.Event();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link OperationDataType.Chat.Operators.Operator }
 * 
 */
public OperationDataType.Chat.Operators.Operator createOperationDataTypeChatOperatorsOperator() {
    return new OperationDataType.Chat.Operators.Operator();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType.BankInfo }
 * 
 */
public UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType.BankInfo createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqTypeBankInfo() {
    return new UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType.BankInfo();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType.Status }
 * 
 */
public UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType.Status createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsTypeStatus() {
    return new UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType.Status();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "ServerStatusDesc")
public JAXBElement<String> createServerStatusDesc(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_ServerStatusDesc_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "AgencyId")
public JAXBElement<String> createAgencyId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_AgencyId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SPNameType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "SPName")
public JAXBElement<SPNameType> createSPName(SPNameType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<SPNameType>(_SPName_QNAME, SPNameType.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRs")
public JAXBElement<UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType> createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRs(UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType>(_UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRs_QNAME, UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRsType.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "RqUID")
public JAXBElement<String> createRqUID(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_RqUID_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "SystemId")
public JAXBElement<String> createSystemId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_SystemId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRq")
public JAXBElement<UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType> createUpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRq(UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType>(_UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRq_QNAME, UpdatePrivateClientManagerTaskRqType.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "BranchId")
public JAXBElement<String> createBranchId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_BranchId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "OperUID")
public JAXBElement<String> createOperUID(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_OperUID_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Long }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "StatusCode")
public JAXBElement<Long> createStatusCode(Long value) {
    return new JAXBElement<Long>(_StatusCode_QNAME, Long.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "StatusDesc")
public JAXBElement<String> createStatusDesc(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_StatusDesc_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigDecimal }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "CurAmt")
public JAXBElement<BigDecimal> createCurAmt(BigDecimal value) {
    return new JAXBElement<BigDecimal>(_CurAmt_QNAME, BigDecimal.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "StatusType")
public JAXBElement<String> createStatusType(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_StatusType_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "RbBrchId")
public JAXBElement<String> createRbBrchId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_RbBrchId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "RegionId")
public JAXBElement<String> createRegionId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_RegionId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "RbTbBrchId")
public JAXBElement<String> createRbTbBrchId(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_RbTbBrchId_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link XMLGregorianCalendar }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "RqTm")
public JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar> createRqTm(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    return new JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar>(_RqTm_QNAME, XMLGregorianCalendar.class, null, value);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Вот ваши Java бины (убрал только комментарии).

**Properties.class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Properties")
public class Properties extends PropertiesType {
}
```

**PropertiesType.class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Properties_Type", propOrder = { "property" })
@XmlSeeAlso({ Properties.class })
public class PropertiesType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Property", required = true)
    protected List<PropertiesType.Property> property;

    public List<PropertiesType.Property> getProperty() {
        if ( property == null ) {
            property = new ArrayList<PropertiesType.Property>();
        }
        return this.property;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "key", "value" })
    public static class Property {

        @XmlElement(name = "Key", required = true)
        protected String key;
        @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
        protected String value;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String value) {
            this.key = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Конструируем объект и сериализуем.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    Property prop1 = new Property();
    prop1.setKey("key1");
    prop1.setValue("value1");

    Property prop2 = new Property();
    prop2.setKey("key2");
    prop2.setValue("value2");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    List<PropertiesType.Property> data = properties.getProperty();
    data.add(prop1);
    data.add(prop2);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Properties.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output", true);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(properties, writer);
    String out = writer.toString();

    System.out.println(out);

}
```

**Вывод**

```
<Properties>
    <Property>
        <Key>key1</Key>
        <Value>value1</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Key>key2</Key>
        <Value>value2</Value>
    </Property>
</Properties>
```

Как собирать объект в явном виде написано прямо в комментариях.

> This accessor method returns a reference to the live list, not a
>   snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the returned list
>   will be present inside the JAXB object. This is why there is not a
>   `set` method for the property property.
>
> For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
>
> ```
>     getProperty().add(newItem);
> ```

Comment: Так то да, но у меня есть куча классов которые не стринги, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Извините, но это не интересно. Вы постите простыню нечитабельного кода, и не хотите думать от слова "совсем". В примере, в `Properties` передается тоже не `String`, а объект. Нет никакой сложности проделать тоже самое с любым уровнем вложенности; конструктор и коллекции - это азы языка. Упростите себе задачу. Например, чтобы передать на удаленную систему XML определенного вида нужно сериализовать класс `SomeRequest`, получить и десериализовать ответ в виде `SomeResponse`. Обычно такое взаимодействие с WEB сервисами организуется через WSDL. Возможно, вы вообще не тем занимаетесь.

Comment: Я уже два дня разбираюсь с этим кодом, получился у меня такой код, PropertiesType.Property prop = new PropertiesType.Property();
и в prop есть метод только setKey and setValue только для String, и List<PropertiesType.Property> data = properties.getProperty();
    data.add(prop1);       принимает у меня только properties объекты, но не объекты

Comment: Кое как сгенерировал xml файл, и в итоге получается что корневой элемент совсем другой, но именно туда все setится, но marshaller ругается что он не указан корневым элементом

Comment: ничего что я вручную подставил ему аннотацию xml root, валидацию он не проходит но на экран печатает xml,